# How to create ItemTemplate by code in Telerik

Tags: telerik-grid

I created the following piece of code using Telerik:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="50%" AllowSorting="True">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="OrderID" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" PageSize="5">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Order" HeaderText="Order" UniqueName="Order">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Order") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

How I can declare the code that is within the "ItemTemplate" (the "Label") in the Page.Init?

Answer (score -1):

I think you would need to use the grids ItemDataBound event rather than Page.Init, here is a code example from the telerik site showing how you might implement your logic http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-conditional-image-display-in-grid-column.html

Answer (score -1):

> Creating Template Columns Programmatically
>   When creating template columns programmatically, the grid must be generated completely in the code-behind using the Page_Init event. Then, you must create the templates dynamically in the code-behind and assign them to the ItemTemplate and EditItemTemplate properties of the column. To create a template dynamically, you must define a custom class that implements the ITemplate interface. Then you can assign an instance of this class to the ItemTemplate or EditTemplateTemplate property of the GridTemplateColumn object.

From [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-programmatic-creation.html)

You might have problems with the above approach. If it doesn't work, try creating the whole column programmatically. This above link shows how to implement it.